# Java Self-Contained Application Packaging delete files on uninstall

Tags: java, packager

I am using java packager to create an `exe` for a java application.

When the application runs, it places files in the `appdata` folder for updating the application.

How can I delete these files when the user uninstalls the application?

Comment: Have you find any solution for this?